# Rspec: mock a nested/dependency injected object

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection, rspec, mocking

I am having trouble mocking an injected object. For example:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(bar = Bar.new)
    @bar = bar
  end

  def run
    @bar.do_something_cool
  end
end

# Rspec
describe Foo do
  it "should do something cool" do
    mock_bar = mock("bar")
    mock_bar.stub(:do_something_cool).and_return(nil)

    real_foo = Foo.new(mock_bar)
    real_foo.run

    mock_bar.should_receive(:do_something_cool).once
  end
end
```

If I run this, the spec fails because it says the "do_something_cool" is never called.

```
 expected: 1 time
 received: 0 times
```

However, if I do not stub "do_something_cool", I get the following error

```
Mock "bar" received unexpected message :do_something_cool with (no args)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mock_bar.should_receive(:do_something_cool).once
```

should be before

```
real_foo.run
```

Comment: I've always wished RSpec's DSL would allow mock objects to be used in a slightly less back-to-front way, like: `expect { some_code }.to invoke(mock, :do_something_cool).once`

Comment: That pattern of mocking is called the "test spy". It's an object that remembers what happened to it so you can assert after the fact on what has already occurred. You typically use it as a stub originally so you can set up it's state/behaviour. Look how 'Verify' works in Moq in C# or http://notahat.com/not_a_mock in ruby.